Quick Filter Toolbar not working correctly in Thunderbird
I'm using Thunderbird 115.13.0 (32bit, ESR) on Windows 10 and have had problems with the Quick Filter Toolbar for quite some time now. The Mozilla Support page show a picture how the Toolbar should look like:
https://assets-prod.sumo.prod.webservices.mozgcp.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2023-06-29-12-32-32-1dea10.png
(Sorry, my first question, so I'm not allowed yet to include pictures in my post ...)
In my Thunderbird, the "Filter message by: Sender, ..." beneath the search field is not showing up anymore and this is absolutely driving me crazy. Even worse, one of the not-showing-filters is seemingly checked, which renders the toolbar completely useless for me at present.
If you have any idea what is causing this and how to fix it, you would absolutely make my day because this is one of the main ways of me searching my e-mails.
Thanks
Sebastian

OK, I finally found the answer!!!
The add-on "expression-search" has an option, which hides the regular quick-search toolbars. Unchecking this option did not work, but removing the addon finally gave me back my much needed buttons. This seems to be a bug in the extension (since you cannot unselect the option), but since I'm not really using this addon, removing it solved my problem.
Cheers
Sebastian
